# org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: hql request syntax

Tags: hibernate

i have a table named Champ ,
i want to increment all the ids after an int i by 1 ,
and of course idChamp is the primary key

```
public void increase(int i){

   Query query=factory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("UPDATE Champ c set c.idChamp=c.idChamp+1 WHERE c.idChamp>= :var ORDER BY DESC");
     query.setParameter("var",i+1);         
     int result=query.executeUpdate();
     System.out.println(result);
                                }
```

and i tried this too

```
   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void increase(int i){

         String hql = "from Champ c WHERE c.idChamp>=:num ORDER BY DESC";
         List<Champ> lesChamps = ( factory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql)
         .setParameter("num", i)).list();
         for (Champ c: lesChamps){
             c.setIdChamp(c.getIdChamp()+1);
         }
                                }
```

Comment: so what is the problem? you are not sure about the query? why you have Orderby in an update query?

Comment: because if it starts from the top i ll have 2 objects with same id

Comment: dudee the query gives a org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException

Comment: Can't you retrieve the collection first and increase the id's one by one?

Comment: like this , not working